# Conditional return from a database access method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[Winforms .NET 4.0]

I want to be able to call a method and either return a bool or an object. Or anythign that can satisfy my example.

Example:

Method query the database. If the returned row is null i want the calling method to know this in order to call another check method. If the query returns a row with data i should return the data object.

One way i thought is to use the out keyword. Make the method return bool and initialize the returning object prior to calling the method.

After the method runs i could check if true and then manipuate the object...

Is this a good way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Method query the database. If the returned row is null i want the calling method to know this in order to call another check method.

Why not just return a `null` reference then? Would you ever want `null` to mean anything else? (For example, would you ever want to represent that a null value has been found, with a different meaning to the value not being found in the first place?)

Comment: I am silly...Most probably you mean to have the method return the object i want and just make the object = null when i have no data. Correct?

Comment: If the return type is a reference type you can return `null` as an indicator that no row has been found. Otherwise you can use a `Nullable<T>` as return type, e.g. `Nullable<int>` or `int?` and return `null` as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the TryParse idiom of returning a bool and populating an out reference. Another option is returning a tuple.